# Alamofire .GET returning nil for response and JSON

Tags: swift, alamofire

this code is returning nil for the response and the json, any idea what the problem is? the url is a link to an api endpoint

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadData(){

        let url = "http://httpbin.org/get"

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(json)



    }



    }
}
```

it returns this

{ URL: http://httpbin.org/get }
nil
nil

Comment: What does the error tell you?

Answer (score 3):

Always make sure to check your `error` case. If an error occurred, Alamofire will make sure to bubble it up to your response serializer. Your request is failing and since you are not printing out the error or checking against it, you don't know that that is the problem. If you update your `loadData` method to the following, you will have a much better idea of how to proceed.

```
func loadData() {
    let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(json)
            println(error)
    }

    debugPrintln(request)
}
```

If the `error` message doesn't provide you enough information, then you can move to the `cURL` command that is generated by the `debugPrintln` message.

Comment: Hi @Maxwell, did you end up solving your issue? If my answer helped you along the way, could you mark it as such to be a good community user? Cheers.